# Internal Error when executing a JSON request

Tags: android, json

I'm developing an application which communicate with a server through JSON messages.

Some messages was send and received the result properly. But one of my routines thrown an Error and I'm not sure if it is my problem or from the server.

The error is:

```
 org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Internal Server Error
     at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:71)
     at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:59)
     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:657)
     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:627)
     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:616)
     at br.com.iba.dao.DLS.post(DLS.java:121)
     at br.com.iba.dao.DLS.fulfill(DLS.java:151)
     at br.com.iba.LibraryActivity$3.doAction(LibraryActivity.java:123)
     at br.com.iba.LibraryActivity$SwitchListener.setSelected(LibraryActivity.java:208)
     at br.com.iba.LibraryActivity$SwitchListener.access$0(LibraryActivity.java:204)
     at br.com.iba.LibraryActivity$ButtonGroup.onClick(LibraryActivity.java:230)
     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My code to post is this:

```
    private String post(String json) {
        int TIMEOUT_MILLISEC = 10000; // = 10 seconds
        HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);

        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(
                "https://my server url");
        try {
            StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json);
            entity.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
                    "application/json"));
            request.setEntity(entity);

            ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            return client.execute(request, handler);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
    }
```

I read on BasicResponseHandler Doc:

"A ResponseHandler that returns the response body as a String for successful (2xx) responses. If the response code was >= 300, the response body is consumed and an HttpResponseException is thrown. If this is used with {@link org.apache.http.client.HttpClient#execute( org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest, ResponseHandler), HttpClient may handle redirects (3xx responses) internally."

So now I believe it was an server side error. I need to know which exactly error is that.

Thanks

Comment: Re whether the problem is in the server or the client, I speculate that there might be a clue in "Internal Server Error" :-)  That's the typical HTTP 500 text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your server is returning a 500 Internal Server Error response status. So the issue is on your server.

Comment: Hmm... The StackTrace should be more specific in this point, thank's for the info. I will mark as right when I solve it on the server side.

Comment: We test the same JSON package into the Server and it's works properly. The error is probably on my side. Maybe the error was on "org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:71)"

Comment: " If the response code was >= 300, the response body is consumed and an HttpResponseException is thrown", thanks

Comment: Is your application an android? Are you running the network calls on UI thread?